# ext.js grid inside accordion: how to set the grid header to the accordion's

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, accordion, gridpanel

I am trying to create a grid within an accordion panel. Thing is, grid already has a header, so I get 2 headers, one beneath the other. My intention is to add sort buttons and filter search box to the header. I just don't really know which one should I hide, and how..

And.. I am a Newb to js and ext.js..
Using ext.js 4.2.2:

contactListView.js:

```
Ext.define( 'AcWeb.view.ContactListView',
{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'contact-list-view',
    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.feature.Grouping'
    ],
    collapsible: true,
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
    frame: false,
    resizable: false,

    initComponent: function()
    {
        this.store = new AcWeb.store.ContactList();
        this.columns = [
        {
            text     : 'Contact List',
            width    : '100%',
            sortable : true,
            flex     : 1,
            dataIndex: 'userName'
        }];

        this.callParent();
    },

});
```

container accordion - westview.js:

```
Ext.define('AcWeb.view.WestView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.layout.container.Accordion',
        'AcWeb.view.ContactListView'

    ],

    xtype: 'west-view',
    layout: 'accordion',
    title: '',
    defaults: {
        bodyPadding: 10
    },



    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [
            {
                // preventHeader: true,
                // html: 'david'
                //hidden: true ,
                // title: 'Accordion Item 3',
                xtype: 'contact-list-view'
            }, {
                title: 'Accordion Item 3',
                html: 'moshe'
            }, {
                title: 'Accordion Item 4',
                html: 'david'
            }, {
                title: 'Accordion Item 5',
                html: 'davidmoshe'
            }]
        });

        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Comment: You didn't post any code, how do you expect people to help?

Comment: right... I updated my question..

Comment: I added both accordion and grid.. hope my question is now clearer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was simple...

To hide the headers simply add:

```
hideHeaders: true
```

Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, remove "title" property from the grid.

```
title: 'some title' //remove this
```

By doing this, it will remove the header of the grid

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `title:''` from the accordion config.

Comment: Can't! Accordion title seem to fill some holy purpose, like managing the accordion. It will just not render with title:none / title:'' ...